# Complementary integrable vector fields

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, foliations, hopf-fibration

Let $(M,g)$ be  a  Riemannian manifold. Assume that $X$ is  a non vanishing vector field tangent to $M$.(Or  assume  that  we  have  a one  dimensional  foliation of $M$). Under what geometric  conditions we are sure that the codimension one  distribution on $M$  orthogonal to $X$ (orthogonal to   $F$) is  integrable? Is there a global  geometro-dynamical meaning  for  such possible conditions?

In  particular, what is  the  answer  for the standard metric  of  $S^{3}$  and  its  one  dimensional  foliation by  circle arising from  Hopf  fibration? In this  particular  case, if  this  2  dim.  distribution is  integrable, to what extent this  2. dim foliation is  studied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obstruction against integrability of the orthogonal is called curvature
for the (Ehresmann) connection given by orthogonal projection onto the distribution generated by $X$. See section 17 of

- Peter W. Michor: Topics in Differential Geometry. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, Vol. 93 American Mathematical Society, Providence, 2008. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf)

where the situation is slightly more special (the orbit space is a manifold, and the projection is a fiber bundle).
Or see the paper for a more general situation (the vertical bundle, here generated by $X$, need not be integrable either, and then you have curvature and cocurvature):

- Peter W. Michor: Graded derivations of the algebra of differential forms associated with a connection. Differential Geometry, Pe\ niscola, 1988, \eds F.J. Carreras, O. Gil-Medrano, A.M. Naveira Lecture Notes in Math. 1410 (1989), 249--261, Springer-Verlag, Berlin. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/der.pdf)

In the case of $S^3$ and the Hopf fibration, the orbit space is $S^2$, and the connection is a principal $S^1$-connection whose curvature 2-form is a multiple of the volume form on $S^2$, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Prof. Michor thank you very much for your very interesting answer and  your  linked  references. I 'll try to learn the details of your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's easier than the general curvature case:  Let $X^\flat$ be the $1$-form dual to $X$ via the metric $g$.  Then the orthogonal plane field to the integral curves of $X$ is integrable if and only if 
$$
X^\flat \wedge \mathrm{d} X^\flat = 0.
$$

In the case of the $3$-sphere and the vector field $X$ that generates the Hopf fibration, the $3$-form $X^\flat \wedge \mathrm{d} X^\flat$ is nowhere vanishing, so the $2$-plane field is not integrable, so there is no foliation to discuss.  In particular, $X^\flat$ defines a contact structure on the $3$-sphere.

Moreover, Haefliger (Comment. Math. Helv. **32** (1958), 249–329) proved that there is no real-analytic foliation of a simply-connected compact $3$-manifold by surfaces.  (Reeb famously constructed a *smooth* foliation of $S^3$, though.)

If you are looking for information about codimension $1$ foliations of manifolds, you should, perhaps, look up references that discuss secondary characteristic classes, such as the Godbillon-Vey class, and their geometric and dynamical meaning.  A good place to start would be H. Blaine Lawson's article *Foliations* (Bulletin of the AMS **80** (1974), 369–418).

**Note:**  In the first version of this answer (written in 2014), I had mistakenly attributed Haefliger's theorem to Arnol'd.  My thanks to Dan Asimov for pointing out my error.

Comment: Prof  Bryant Thank you very much for  your answer. I 'll try to learn  about Godbillon Vey class and its  dynamic and geometric  meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't it André Haefliger who proved that there exists no real-analytic foliation of the 3-sphere by surfaces?

Comment: Dear  Prof. Asimov. Thank you very much for your answer. I did not heared (or I do not remember) of this theorem .the version I was aware of was the following"Non exsictence of a codimension 1 foliation with non trivial holonomy(in dim 3). Thanks for informing me of this theorem.

Comment: Dan:  Thanks for pointing that out.  I wrote my answer off the top of my head and didn't realize that I had mis-remembered the attribution.  I'm not sure why I have Arnol'd connected with this result.  Maybe it's because I read about it in a book or article by Arnol'd and didn't remember that he attributed it to Haefliger.  I'll fix my answer, but put in a note so that your remark won't be orphaned.

Comment: Dear Prof. Asimov  thank you again for your answer and your attention to my question. I would like to ask you to give comment on the following question(i am sorry if this question is unrelated to this post but I had intention to ask you via email but I did not find your email address)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345685/a-linear-map-on-chi-infty-mathbbr2-arising-from-the-cauchy-integral-f